# Работа цикла для обхода объекта

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Вопрос вот в чем. На сколько я понимаю, для корректной работы  циклу, например while  или for необходимы счетчики, чтобы определить где закончить обход. Есть пример кода, связанный с односвязанным списком. Вот пример кода:

```
var list = {
  value: 1,
  next: {
    value: 2,
    next: {
      value: 3,
      next: {
        value: 4,
        next: null
      }
    }
  }
};

function printList(list) {
  var tmp = list;

  while (tmp) {
    alert( tmp.value );
    tmp = tmp.next;
  }

}

printList(list);
```

Каким образом цикл без использования счетчика знает, где закончить и как он вообще переходит к след.итерации?

p.s. заканчивает наверно на null, остальное непонятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var array = [true, true, true, false, true];
var length = array.length;
var count = 0;

while(array[count++]){}

console.log(count, length);
```

Сначала разберем работу цикла. Цикл работает до тех пор, пока условие в скобках возвращает `true`. В примере выше длина массива равняется пяти, а значение свойства `count` четырем, т.к. цикл прерывается на предпоследнем элементе.

А как известно из приведение типов `boolean 0, null, undefined === false`. То есть, если в массив поставить любое из перечисленных значений, то все останется по прежнему.

```js
var a = {name: 'a', next:null};
var b = {name: 'b', next:null};

a.next = b;

var c = a;
// теперь с имеет ссылку на а у которого в свойстве
// next находится ссылка на b.
console.log(c.name == 'a', c.next.name == 'b');

c = c.next;
// а теперь мы присвоем переменной с
// ссылку на с.next что равносильно 
// c = b, ведь с === a, а a.next == b
console.log(c.name == 'b');

c = c.next;
// идем дальше и снова присваиваем с
// ссылку на с.next. Но как мы помним
// на предыдущем шаге c === b, а у b
// next === null, что в свою очередь
// переводится в false и останавливает цикл.
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.... все понял УРА!!! надо было просто глубже капнуть в работу циклов...